# Stack Overflow Developer Story's Traditional View needs a space

Tags: bug, developer-story

I think there should be more space between "Your profile is currently set toblock all messages and searches." If my browser data is needed, "macOS 10.13.3 Safari 11.0.3(13604.5.6)".

[image: job status needs more space]

Comment: I don't think we would want to**confuse everyone with a lack of a space.**

Comment: -0.5 for the lack of the red free-hand drawn circle... without it, there just confusion all around...

Comment: @kayess You're welcome.

Comment: This is**design.**

Comment: @RickAstley -1 for no Rickrolling attempt. Otherwise thank you for your precious work. :)

Comment: @kayess It's been rough these days..

Comment: Did you mean: free-hand drawn**circle**?